# Real-time hard-drive space usage logging software?

Tags: windows-7, windows, hard-drive, storage, performance-monitor

I'm looking for a (Windows 7-compatible) tool that monitors and logs continuously how the space on my hard-drive is used.

I use Windows and my hard-drive is overflowing with automatically downloaded updates, temporary files and other stuff that I don't have direct control over. I would like to be able to say: "Yesterday the disk was 80% full, now it is 99% full and here's a list of files that have been added/changed since yesterday."

Disk analysis software like WinDirStat are useful to display the current space usage but cannot track which files were added when.

Thanks,
Matt

Comment: This would be quite resource hungry.

Comment: What @Shiki said, your talking monitoring every byte written to the disk, there are billions of them.

Comment: Any Disk analysis software like WinDirStat that has the capability to generate a report could fulfill your requirements.  You just have to run the program through a daily task.

Comment: I know that this would be resource hungry, but it might not be as bad as you think since during normal use, my computer's processor is not working hard and when I'm doing resource-hungry computatitons, I could always switch the logging off temporarily. Also, many programs already do this type of monitoring (Dropbox and the likes) and it doesn't seem so bad.

Comment: Check out Space Sniffer. Not sure if it knows what you want, though.